# Sphinx LaTeX markup limitations

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx

I'm trying to do three really basic things inside of a multi-line math mode in Sphinx (version 1.1.2-1).

1. Write underscores as part of my variable names even in math mode;
2. Use the `\big`, `\biggl`, etc., delimiters to make large brackets and parentheses;
3. and include regular text as part of equations.

Note the following two things. (1) I am using a raw string in my Python code for the Sphinx-markup documentation, so extra backslashes are not needed for escape characters, and (2) I am not doing inline math mode, which is delimited like this in Sphinx:

```
:math:`Some math stuff goes here` regular text could go here...
```

Instead, I am doing multi-line stuff, often like `eqnarray` in LaTeX:

```
.. math::
    DividendYield &=& \frac{DVT(t)}{CurrentMarketCap} \\
    Avg_Assets &=& \biggl( A/B \biggr) \textrm { when B is not zero...}
```

Currently, I get Sphinx errors (and the generated doc pages look like gibberish), that say things like:

```
Unknown LaTeX command: textrm
```

The same happens for `\biggl`. For the underscore, it just always interprets it as if I am denoting a subscript, but if I use `\textunderscore` or other tricks then it throws the same sorts of errors as above.

Underscores within math mode, the `textrm` command, and big delimiters are extremely basic parts of every native TeX package I've ever used. So why are they inaccessible through Sphinx?

**Update**

One particular Python file that I am working on calculates Book Equity data for me. So below, when you see the stuff about BookEquity, that's the reference. I can't run our build-docs process except through a version control system, so making a reproducible error was easiest if I just modified an existing file.

However, all I did was to add the following class function in my code, with a simple docstring.

```
def foo(self):
    r"""
    Sample docstring

    .. math::
        Ax &=& b \\
        Cx &=& \biggl(\frac{x/y}\biggr) \textrm{ if y is not zero.}
    """
    pass
```

And then the image below is the output coming from building the docs with Sphinx 1.1.2-1.

[image: Snippet of the generated doc page showing the error exactly as it appears from Sphinx.]

If you right-click and select 'view image' you can see a better version.

Comment: Sorry don't know about Sphinx, but I think the underscores need to be escaped `\_`, and you could try using `\text{}` instead of `\textrm` (requires the `amsmath` pacakge).

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. `\_` and `\text` were things that I immediately tried back when I first got this error. The Sphinx doc pages specifically state that they use `amsmath`. `\text` actually seems to work, but this doesn't help solve the problem really. It's a good workaround for that 1/3 of the question though.

Comment: Could you post some of the generated LaTeX code, e.g. for your examples?

Comment: We have a Tex/LaTeX site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/ which might be more appropriate for your question. Have a look around there, and if it looks promising then can refund your bounty and migrate this question over there. Flag to let us know if you want to do this.

Comment: @KeV: I tried posting it there first and they closed it as off-topic. I put this in the question above, but one of the people who edited the question took that info out. As an aside, this kind of stuff is annoying about the stack exchange sites. They generally remove too much content under the guise that it's not needed or is off-topic, but in terms of the trade-off between just storing the info and having it vs. saving space and reducing clutter, I think just keeping the info wins hands down. Almost none of it is actually clutter. Admins are just hypervigilant about clutter.

Comment: I opened [this tex.stackexchange.com meta question about it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2824/are-questions-about-python-sphinx-documentation-tex-markup-off-topic/2830#comment8007_2830) when my original question was closed.

Comment: @Roland: generic TeX code doesn't much matter. It's specifically Sphinx's interpretation of the TeX code that matters. The generic TeX code in a regular TeX document compiles just fine. I just need to figure out why it does not in Sphinx.

Comment: @EMS: when using the example above, Sphinx 1.1.3 (which is not that different from 1.1.2, looking at the repo) produces output that can be compiled with pdflatex.

Comment: That was already mentioned at the linked tex.stackexchange.com meta question above, and in the bounty I noted that version issues aren't that helpful for me. I'm on a work network so I have to work with this Sphinx version for now.

Comment: @EMS: the last changes to the code that outputs the math stuff (`mathbase.py`) was _before_ the release of 1.1.2. So that behavior hasn't changed between 1.1.2 and 1.1.3.

Comment: @EMS - that did surprise me ever so slightly, but that said it looks like your in good hands here.

Comment: I think my original question at the TeX site should have been worded a lot better and expanded with an example. But I don't think it should have been closed. Hopefully the meta question I opened will help... but yes, people here are offering good suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to edit the standard configuration file that `sphinx-quickstart` creates, otherwise sphinx will barf at math blocks. In the file `conf.py`, I changed

```
extensions = []
```

to

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.pngmath']
```

After that the following rst file more-or-less worked;

```
.. foo documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Thu Oct 25 11:04:31 2012.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to foo's documentation!
===============================

Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

This is the first chapter
=========================

Instead, I am doing multi-line stuff, often like eqnarray in LaTeX:

.. math::
    DividendYield &=& \frac{DVT(t)}{CurrentMarketCap} \\
    Avg_Assets &=& \biggl( A/B \biggr) \textrm { when B is not zero...}
```

It produced the following LaTeX code for the math fragment:

```
\chapter{This is the first chapter}
\label{index:welcome-to-foo-s-documentation}\label{index:this-is-the-first-chapter}
Instead, I am doing multi-line stuff, often like eqnarray in LaTeX:
\begin{gather}
\begin{split}DividendYield &=& \frac{DVT(t)}{CurrentMarketCap} \\
Avg_Assets &=& \biggl( A/B \biggr) \textrm { when B is not zero...}\end{split}\notag\\\begin{split}\end{split}\notag
\end{gather}
```

The choice of using the combination of split and gather seems a bit weird to me, and obviously doesn't work well with the code you wrote for eqnarray, but this is hardcoded in Sphinx.

Running pdflatex did stop at `\end{gather}`, with the error `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.` but I was able to proceed past that by entering nonstopmode. This give me the following result:

[image: test image]

While there is still something wrong with the alignment (because of the differences between the `split` and `eqnarray` environments), the textrm and biggl seem to work fine. (Note that you'll still have to escape the underscore in `Average_Assets`, but that is par for the course, AFAICT).

You *might* get away with postprocessing the generated LaTeX code, e.g. by replacing `\begin{gather}\begin{split}` and `\end{split}\notag\\\begin{split}\end{split}\notag\end{gather}` by the math environment of your choice.

**Update**:

The screenshot from the update seems to be from a webpage, not a LaTeX document! So it looks to me that what is producing the error is the handler that converts the LaTeX math notation so something a browser can show. That will be probably be either `MathJax` or `jsMath`. From looking at the code, `pngmath` would produce other error messages. According to [this page](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm), your code snippet *should* work in mathjax. From the [jsMath symbols page](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsmath/symbols/welcome.html), it doesn't look like jsmath supports `\Biggl`. So my best guess is that SPhinx is configured to use jsMath. A peek at the source of the generated web page should tell you what is used to render the math. If my guess is correct, switching the configuration to use mathjax and slightly adapting your equation might fix the problem.

**Update2**: I can definitely confirm that it works fine with MathJax (see below). I don't have jsMath installed, though.

[image: with mathjax]

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. However, I didn't have to do anything to get it to render the math blocks generally. For example, I can make multi-line math blocks just fine, it's only certain commands like `\textrm` that caused errors. Can you explain how this is consistent with the need for the pngmath dealie? I'll have to check with one of our sys admins here to explore this, but it's a promising lead.

Comment: If I left out the pngmath extension, sphinx raised an exception when encountering a math block. I had to look at the source to see why, but I didn't write down the particulars. Maybe your sysadmin or (more likely) package builders changed something from the vanilla Sphinx? (since there is a -1 after the version number)

Comment: No, 1.1.2-1 is the standard from Sphinx. Sphinx marks versions that way. There is 1.1.3-2, for example. The fact that math blocks render for me at all makes me guess that we already use the pngmath, or some other equivalent, option in the configs. I'm guessing it's just the Sphinx version that allows you to execute the commands that are causing me errors? For example, If I take out \biggl and I change \textrm to just \text, then the above example you gave compiles correctly for me and the docs look right. But if I change back \biggl or \textrm, and nothing else, then it breaks.

Comment: Is it _sphinx_ that produces the errors, or _LaTeX_? I couldn't tell from your question.

Comment: It's Sphinx, telling me that things like \textrm are not valid LaTeX commands. They clearly are (copy/pasting the code will work immediately in a TeX editor, even accounting for the adjustment to gather/split formatting).

Comment: That's really weird, because I searched the Spinx 1.1.2 source code for the words 'Unknown', 'LaTeX' or 'command', and got _nothing_ that looked like the error message that you put in your question.

Comment: See the update. I made a reproducible error and took a screenshot of exactly what Sphinx says.

Comment: It could be catching TeX errors and passing them on, so maybe the error is not generated within Sphinx. But since Sphinx promises to be using AMSMath, it shouldn't get errors when using these commands.

Comment: I do not think these are TeX errors, but _javascript_ errors. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to follow up on it. I will check that out and give it a try. It sounds promising that it could be a post-Sphinx error.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

As mentioned, sphinx uses `gather` and `split` for math mode. According to the [AMS math guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) split takes a single `$` sign. So

```
.. math::
    DividendYield &= \frac{DVT(t)}{CurrentMarketCap} \\
    Avg_Assets &= \biggl( A/B \biggr) \textrm { when B is not zero...} \\
    Avg \_ Assets &= \biggl(\frac{A}{B}\biggr) \textrm{ when B is not zero...}

.. autofunction:: mymodule.foo
```

with foo defined as

```
def foo(self):
    r"""Sample docstring

    .. math::
        Ax &= b \\
        Cx &= \biggl( \frac{x}{y} \biggr) \textrm{ if y is not zero.}
    """
    pass
```

renders fine with latexpdf and to html with the [MathJax extension](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/math.html#module-sphinx.ext.mathjax).

[image: sphinx-math]

Note that I used `\_` for the underscore in math mode , which worked, but `\textunderscore` didn't work (You have to load additional packages I think, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6550/where-is-textunderscore-defined)  on tex.stackexchange.com).
So as it comes out, I think your question is clearly a `Tex` question.

I don't remove my previous answer, however it is only applicable for the latex builder, not for the html builder.

**Original answer**

Sphinx produces "unusual" latex code. It uses `gather` and `split` for equations (have a look at the latex source it generates).

The problem is, that there is no simple way to modify the latex source it produces. You have to post-process the latex source to get "scientific" grade latex code.

Sphinx is designed for html docs (and by web developers I think), latex (and scientific "problems" like numbered figures, tables and equations) doesn't seem to be the main focus of the project. By the way, your code renders fine to html with the mathjax extension.

I think I remember some criticism by the docutils developers on this topic too: docutils has a latex builder (which seems to be "better"), but this builder is not used by sphinx.

There was once an announcement of a project called `relatex` ([link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sphinx-dev/XOZAXsErVDU)) on the mailing list to post-process the latex code created by sphinx. But I'm not sure about the development status.
I used my own code, which I made available [here](https://github.com/bmu/sphinx-latex) (unfortunately it is a mixture of German an English). I don't think that it is very useful, because I decided that it is to complicated to post-process sphinx latex and I switched to pure latex. So I didn't developed it further. However the basic steps are

- create your own latex style and template
- let sphinx create it's latex code
- post-process the latex code and paste it into your template
- use a building system for LaTeX to generate the pdf from your code

I adapted the sphinx Makefile to do this in a single step. As the building system I used [`rubber`](https://launchpad.net/rubber/) (nowadays I would use [`latexmk`](http://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/support/latexmk/)).

Comment: This is helpful as background information on Sphinx. Could you write a little more about the specific process to post-process Sphinx output so that the TeX will render? That may be an option for me, especially if I can write a Python script to automatically do that each time I build the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Now (2016) Sphinx math directive has option `:nowrap:` returning full control to the user, so doing just

```
.. math::
   :nowrap:

   \begin{eqnarray}
      y    & = & ax^2 + bx + c \\
      f(x) & = & x^2 + 2xy + y^2
   \end{eqnarray}
```

renders fine in both html and latexpdf.