# How to type large curly brackets in reStructuredText / Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

How to type large curly brackets in reStructuredText / Sphinx?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [math mode](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/math.html), which uses LaTeX syntax, to render braces and control their size:

```
.. math::

    \{ \big\{ \Big\{ \bigg\{ \Bigg\{

    (  \big(  \Big(  \bigg(  \Bigg(
```

will give you something like this:

[image: braces and brackets of various sizes various]

although be aware of the [limitations of basic math mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017397/sphinx-latex-markup-limitations/13070475): these symbols need `extensions = ['sphinx.ext.pngmath']` in your `conf.py` to work.

Comment: The Docutils standard math directive and role support for HTML5 via MathML fails with `\big` ... but works with `\bigl` and `\bigr` (cf. https://www.docutils.org/docs/ref/rst/mathematics.html#delimiter-sizes).