# Is there a hardcopy of the django documentation?

Tags: django, documentation

I like reading books more than reading ebooks.

- Is there a nicely printed version of the latest django documentation?

I know it exists in pdf and that the pdf could be printed. That's not an option for me, though: the pdf is not nicely typeset (I mean it's sphinx..., typesetting is important if you have a lot to read) and +1000 pages are too much to print.

Thanks

Comment: Just for the record's sake this is **not a question for a** book on django, it is asking for the official django documentation in printed form. Knowing where to find that or how to generate that is, I think, expert knowledge. I am not asking for opinions on nice django books or whatever. I just want the docs. And there is a valid answer.

Comment: PDFs in case someone does want them: https://readthedocs.org/projects/django/downloads/. And FWIW, the formatting is pretty good IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no hardcopy as it will be outdated before the ink is dry.

You can generate docs yourself. The Docs Readme says it all. Docs uses reStructuredText and Sphinx. This is what Django gives you and the starting point for generating any other representation.

Docs [README](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/docs):

> The documentation in this tree is in plain text files and can be
>   viewed using any text file viewer.
>
> It uses ReST (reStructuredText) [1](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/docs), and the Sphinx documentation
>   system [2].   This allows it to be built into other forms for easier
>   viewing and browsing.
>
> To create an HTML version of the docs:
>
> - Install Sphinx (using `sudo pip install Sphinx` or some other method)
> - In this docs/ directory, type `make html` (or `make.bat html` on   Windows) at a shell prompt.
>
> The documentation in _build/html/index.html can then be viewed in a
>   web browser.
>
> [1](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/docs) http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html [2]
>   http://sphinx-doc.org/

In /path/to/django-master/docs/

```
$ make help
Please use `make <target>' where <target> is one of
  html       to make standalone HTML files
  dirhtml    to make HTML files named index.html in directories
  singlehtml to make a single large HTML file
  pickle     to make pickle files
  json       to make JSON files
  htmlhelp   to make HTML files and a HTML help project
  qthelp     to make HTML files and a qthelp project
  devhelp    to make HTML files and a Devhelp project
  epub       to make an epub
  latex      to make LaTeX files, you can set PAPER=a4 or PAPER=letter
  latexpdf   to make LaTeX files and run them through pdflatex
  text       to make text files
  man        to make manual pages
  texinfo    to make a Texinfo source file
  gettext    to make PO message catalogs
  changes    to make an overview of all changed/added/deprecated items
  linkcheck  to check all external links for integrity
  doctest    to run all doctests embedded in the documentation (if enabled)
```

It seems you can generate quite some useful formats!

And reading the make file:

```
# You can set these variables from the command line.
SPHINXOPTS    ?=
SPHINXBUILD   ?= sphinx-build
PAPER         ?=
BUILDDIR      ?= _build
LANGUAGE      ?=
```

Comment: Interesting! In fact, if Sphinx can output files using latexpdf the result could indeed be very nice! (For the record: I do like Sphinx, just in django's case I don't like the *visual* output of it)

Comment: Ah! Okay. Well it seems you can customize all you want. :) I'm curious about the end result.

Comment: I'll see whether I can put something together and put it on github.

Comment: Also, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017397/sphinx-latex-markup-limitations

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think there is; the issue here is that because [django](http://djangoproject.com) is community driven the documentation is continuously changing. Therefore any publication would be out of date before its back from the printers. Yet to mention the fact there is also 6 versions of [django](http://djangoproject.com) currently.

Your best bet is to either use the PDF as mentioned or download the HTML version, then you can modify font, size and layout yourself.